# JS sending data to php to save to XML - returning success without saving

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, web

`HTML/JS sending data to php (on localhost) to save to XML file, it is returning success without saving data in to XML... the XML file is in the root directory. I don't find any errors when i run this function.

following js function is preparing the data from the page and passing it to php.

```
function writeToXML(saveMemberId) {
  console.log("IN writeToXML");

  // Get the value from the HTML input field
  var memberID = document.getElementById('member-id').value;
  var fname = document.getElementById('first-name').value;
  var lname = document.getElementById('last-name').value;
  var mname = document.getElementById('middle-name').value;

  // Construct the URL with query parameters
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/saveXML.php';
  url += '?memberId=' + encodeURIComponent(memberID);
  url += '&fname=' + encodeURIComponent(fname);
  url += '&lname=' + encodeURIComponent(lname);
  url += '&mname=' + encodeURIComponent(mname);
  url += '&oname=' + encodeURIComponent(oname);


  // Make the AJAX request
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log('**XML FILE UPDATE SUCCESS**\*\*');
      alert("**XML FILE UPDATE SUCCESS**\*\*");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log('**XML FILE UPDATE FAILED**\*\*:', error);
      alert("**XML FILE UPDATE FAILED**\*\* ERROR:" + error);
    }
  });
}
```

this is the php code in saveXML.php in the root directory of localhost trying to save it to familyTree.xml which is in the same directory.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Get the values from the GET parameters
$memberIdValue = $_GET['memberId'];
$fnameValue = $_GET['fname'];
$lnameValue = $_GET['lname'];
$mnameValue = $_GET['mname'];
$onameValue = $_GET['oname'];

// Define the key value to search for in the XML file
$memberId = $memberIdValue;

// Load the XML file
$xmlFile = 'familyTree.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

if ($xml === false) {
    echo 'Failed to load XML file.';
} else {
    // Find the person element with the specified memberId
    $person = $xml->xpath('//person[memberId="' . $memberId . '"]');
    if (!empty($person)) {
        $person[0]->fname = $fnameValue;
        $person[0]->lname = $lnameValue;
        $person[0]->mname = $mnameValue;
        $person[0]->oname = $onameValue;
        
        // Save the modified XML back to the file
        $result = $xml->asXML($xmlFile);
        if ($result !== false) {
            if (file_put_contents($xmlFile, $result) !== false) {
                echo 'XML file updated successfully.';
            } else {
                echo 'Failed to save XML file.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Failed to update XML file.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Person with memberId ' . $memberId . ' not found in the XML file.';
    }
}

?>
```

why the data is not saving, also why the response is save success.`

Comment: There are two parts to this and debugging the different parts will be important. Have you tried opening the PHP file and filling in your variables with test data instead of $_GET? Then seeing if that worked? When you just call that file in your browser?

Comment: PHP is sending a response, but you're never printing it in the JavaScript. Add `console.log(response)` to see what it's saying. Or look at the response in the Network tab of DevTools.

Comment: thanks for responding. console.log(response) is printing the entire php code.

Comment: imvain2, thanks for your response. I tried opening the php, it downloaded the .php.

Comment: If the PHP code is being sent by the server, then the server isn't configured to process PHP, you need to do that first.

Comment: Why are you using a GET?  Get is for a request with no body and is used to retrieve data.  If you are sending new data to server your data is in the body of the request which means you need to use POST.  The server is processing just the GET and return a status code of success (200 OK) because it is not even looking at the body of the request.

Comment: jdweng, Thanks for your response POST was giving 405 error when i am testing on localhost. I will use POST again and try and fix 405 error.